# On what side was Jesus' stab wound?

Tags: life-of-jesus, crucifixion

I've always believed that Jesus was stabbed in his left side. That seems to be the common belief. How is that notion supported?

I can't find anything the tells me absolutely in which side he was stabbed, so if there is anyone who says it was the right side, how is that supported?

Comment: Interesting question.  I think you may need a medical opinion for this.  We do know that blood and water came out, which would indicate that Jesus had been dead for some time.  Indeed, He had committed His spirit to the Father.  The best we may be able to do is to assume that if the Roman soldier did wish to verify that He was dead, they probably would have known which side His heart was on and pierced that side.  As the blood was not pumping, I'm not sure the right side would have issued much blood, but the heart certainly could have.  Again, you probably need a medical expert for this.

Comment: This site, [Catholic quick questions](http://www.catholic.com/quickquestions/which-side-of-jesus-body-was-pierced), might help.

Comment: The left side makes sense... since ~90% of the population (presumably including Roman soldiers) are right-handed.  A soldier facing Jesus' body would have gripped a spear with his right hand, and thrusted upward; thus to the left.  But if he was standing behind Jesus, or was left-handed, then the right side would make sense.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This next has nothing to do with the quality of your question, it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Comment: If you're interested in doing some research on this, across literary and artistic sources, a good starting point for the artistic is the Warburg Institute's research gateways, eg [here](http://warburg.sas.ac.uk/?id=300).
As for literary sources, a search for "left side" or "right side" on the [church fathers website](http://www.biblestudytools.com/history/early-church-fathers/post-nicene/vol-13-gregory-ephraim-and-aphrahat/ephraim-syrus/hymn-ii.html#P2540_950220) might reveal a thread.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a verse search question.

Comment: @curiousdannii How do you figure? The Bible doesn't say which side, and I think the asker knows this.

Comment: @fredsbend well then what *is* the basis of this question? Asking for something like Catholic tradition would be okay, but it doesn't.

Comment: @curiousdannii There's only two sides to discuss. A good answer will talk about both options, and I don't think that's too broad or primarily opinion based. Affable Geek's answer is a great start. If I were to answer, I would include traditional perspectives from history and discuss anyone who thinks it was the right side instead of the left.

Comment: @fredsbend That might be an appropriate way to answer a related question. But it's not asking for an overview of theories. Is asking for Truth and the ways we can know the Truth. [Which of these](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409/6071) do you think it comes under?

Comment: @curiousdannii A quick edit fixes that. It's no longer opinion based.

Comment: The Romans were very experienced at crucifixion. Death normally occurs due to asphyxiation. Legs were broken so that they could not bear weight. But piercing the diaghragm was an alternative to hasten death if the victim was lighter. If a lung was also pierced, this was no more effective, but would confirm the effectiveness of the thrust.

Answer (score 7):

From [BibleHub](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/john/19-34.htm):

> Pierced his side - Which side is not mentioned, nor can it be certainly known. The common opinion is that it was the left side. Car. Frid. Gruner (Commentatio Antiquaria Medica de Jesu Christi Morte, 30-36) has attempted to show that it must have been the left side. See Wiseman's Lectures, pp. 161, 162, and Kuinoel on John 19:34, where the arguments of Gruner are fully stated. It is clear that the spear pierced to the region of the heart.

The link really says it all.  John 19:34 only said that his side was pierced.  Beyond that, there is speculation (and a source commentray making the point) but nothing can be ascertained for certain.